# Is CircuitHandler only blazor server side techonology?

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor-webassembly, webassembly

I have blazor app with client and server patrs.

CircuitHandlerService.cs

```cs
    public class CircuitHandlerService : CircuitHandler
    {
        public ConcurrentDictionary<string, Circuit> Circuits { get; set; }

        public CircuitHandlerService()
        {
            Circuits = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Circuit>();
        }

        public override Task OnCircuitOpenedAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Circuits[circuit.Id] = circuit;
            return base.OnCircuitOpenedAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
        }

        public override Task OnCircuitClosedAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Circuit circuitRemoved;
            Circuits.TryRemove(circuit.Id, out circuitRemoved);
            return base.OnCircuitClosedAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
        }

        public override Task OnConnectionDownAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return base.OnConnectionDownAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
        }

        public override Task OnConnectionUpAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return base.OnConnectionUpAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

Handler registration at startup.cs

```cs
services.AddSingleton<CircuitHandler>(new CircuitHandlerService());


app.MapBlazorHub();
```

Without this line

```html
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

handler does not work on server side.

When I include blazor.server.js on my blazor wasm application index.html file

```html
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
```

and then clicks on any html element I see this error:

````
Uncaught (in promise) Error: System.ArgumentException: There is no event handler associated with this event. EventId: '1'. (Parameter 'eventHandlerId')
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetRequiredEventCallback(UInt64 eventHandlerId)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.DispatchEventAsync(UInt64 eventHandlerId, EventFieldInfo fieldInfo, EventArgs eventArgs)
   at InvokeStub_WebRendererInteropMethods.DispatchEventAsync(Object, Object, IntPtr*)
   at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.Infrastructure.DotNetDispatcher.InvokeSynchronously(JSRuntime jsRuntime, DotNetInvocationInfo& callInfo, IDotNetObjectReference objectReference, String argsJson)
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.Infrastructure.DotNetDispatcher.BeginInvokeDotNet(JSRuntime jsRuntime, DotNetInvocationInfo invocationInfo, String argsJson)
    at Ft.endInvokeDotNetFromJS (https://localhost:7251/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:3718)
    at Ft._invokeClientMethod (https://localhost:7251/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:75072)
    at Ft._processIncomingData (https://localhost:7251/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:72696)
    at Ft.connection.onreceive (https://localhost:7251/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:67009)
    at i.onmessage (https://localhost:7251/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:51322)```

What I do wrong?

Net Core 7.0
````